# Object has no method 'click' : web scraping

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to create a web scraping module for our internal project , which is similar to any other website and I face a problem that on the very first page the login is not working. After entering the username and pasword when I click login button it says object has no methord click , I tried the same thing on facebook login just to verify where something wrong with our site or I am doing something wrong , I found the same error again from facebook

TypeError: **Object  has no method 'click**'

Can someone point out what is wrong with my script in line  `$("#loginbutton").click()`

Comment: TypeError: Object <label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="u_0_0"><input value="&#xCB2;&#xCBE;&#xC97;&#xCBF;&#xCA8;&#xCCD; &#xCAE;&#xCBE;&#xCA1;&#xCBF;" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="u_0_0"></label> has no method 'click'   Is the full error message

Comment: Please edit your question with more details and don't post code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `click` with `cheerio`, see: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/586

Perhaps `cheerio` is not what you need, it doesn't simulate user interactions. Maybe you want to check out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).